# Why that lag modifying DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Sometimes, not always, my browser has some delay inserting DOM elements using JavaScript or jQuery. For example, I have this in my html file:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<button id="setBtn"></button>
```

And my Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#setBtn').click(function(){
    var code = getHTMLcode();
    $('#map').append(code);
});
```

This code inserts several DOM nodes, like tables. Sometimes, the browser draws everything very fast when I click in the button, but when I press three times, for example, it takes so long (maybe 5 seconds) to get all drawn (and maybe, the next time it draws it so fast...)

I've tryied to use .html() function instead of .append(), but it happens the same.

Do you know what's happening? 
Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**
This would be the code for getHTMLcode function (here it's simplified for more readability):

```
function getHTMLcode() {
    var code = '<table id="main_table">';

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        code += '<tr>';
        for(var j=0; j<20; j++) {
            code += '<td></td>';
        }
        code += '</tr>';
    }
    code += '</table>';

    return code;
}
```

Comment: What is the code for `getHTMLcode` function?

Comment: Does getHTMLcode() call back to the server?  Is that request taking a long time?  Otherwise it is strictly browser related, I would test out on different browsers.

Comment: @Teemu: I've updated the explanation

Comment: [No lag here.](https://jsfiddle.net/mvhsx0a5/) I took the liberty of moving the button *above* `#map` so that the button didn't move when you clicked it, and added `j` into the table cells. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). Side note: That code creates an invalid document. `id` values **must** be unique, but `main_table` is repeated.

Comment: **[No lag here](https://jsfiddle.net/k10r5yzf/)** either. But, as you'll see in my Fiddle, I would recommend using the Table API instead of creating HTML from strings.

Comment: Yes, sorry guys. My code is much more complex. What I do is to delete the entiry table and re-draw it again. When I draw it again is when lag happens (sometimes).

Comment: @Ommadawn - We can't help you with it without a [mcve], unfortunately.

Comment: **[I've updated my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k10r5yzf/4/)** to delete the prior table (if it exists) as you say your code does, and I still don't have any lag.